# Why does my MySQL Store Procedure not loop?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Here it is. It should loop through 120,000 times but it only does twice. `SELECT DISTINCT barcode FROM albumitemdetails_custom;` returns 120,000 rows when run manually. What is wrong with my code?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`testuser`@`%` PROCEDURE `AlbumMover`()
BEGIN

  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE barcode varchar(100);
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT DISTINCT barcode FROM albumitemdetails_custom;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;

  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO barcode;

        CALL AlbumMoverGenre(barcode);
        CALL AlbumMoverProducer(barcode);

  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur1;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

In my experience a loop gets broken if there is a `SELECT` statement that returns no results, or the `FETCH` of course. It's impossible to say from your code as you do not show the code for `AlbumMoverGenre` and `AlmbumMoverProducer` but I'd check if this is the case in either procedure.

Just looking at your code something is going wrong in either of the subprocedures.

As it breaks at the second iteration I'd get the resultset of your distinct barcodes query and run the subprocedures with that value, and see what the outcome is.

Comment: Even taking out the subs and putting in basic logging shows that it only loops twice. It's not the other calls.

Comment: have you tried to run the two other subs with the second barcode in your resultset?